# Using WiX heat.exe with a static components

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I am using heat.exe available in WiX3.5 to get the list of components and componentref for the files I want to install. However, for the file which should be installed as windows service, I dont want it to be generated by heat.exe as I need to add `<ServiceInstall>` etc.

I dont want to put the `<serviceinstall>` in xslt as it would make it very ugly code. Right now, I delete the exe before running heat.exe and then copy it back, but this is also not ideal. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that tweaking the heat output with XSLT templates is a kind of recommended approach. Although heat is not that rich in features to consider cases like you mentioned, its ability to apply XSLT to the output covers all possible needs.

Why do you think the code will be ugly? Do you reference the XSLT syntax here or the idea to tweak wxs file in general? Anyway, this piece of code won't change that much, I guess. And once you code it thoroughly and debug it, it won't take much of your time in future.

Comment: Installing the service is one of the key tasks of my WXS and I would like to keep this key code in WXS. It kind of gets hidden away if placed in xsl file. I dont know if it is possible to delete that one node using the xslt.

Comment: It might also be an option to move the service related files out of that folder harvested by heat, and create the WXS for it manually. And yes, XSLT is quite powerful - you can just drop that harvested snippet you'd like not to be picked up, and add it manually. A number of choices here...

Comment: Thanks Yan. I will give it a try.